# Segfault in client disconnection

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have a simple client-server program implemented in C where a client can send integers to a server and the server replies with their sums. However, there is a troubling Segmentation fault (core dumped) shown on the server side whenever the client disconnects suddenly. 
The Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 5010

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buf[BUFSIZ], buf2[BUFSIZ], message[BUFSIZ], serverReply[BUFSIZ];
    int SOCKET;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    SOCKET = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (SOCKET < 0) {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Socket created\n");
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if (connect(SOCKET, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) {
        perror("Could not connect");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(&serverReply, 0, sizeof(serverReply));
    printf("Connected to server.\nEnter first number: ");
    scanf("%s", buf);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Enter second number: ");
    scanf("%s", buf2);
    strcat(buf, " ");
    strcat(buf, buf2);
    strcpy(message, buf);
    if (send(SOCKET, message, strlen(message), 0) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to send message");
        return -1;
    }
    if (recv(SOCKET, serverReply, sizeof(serverReply), 0) < 0) {
        perror("Could not receive message");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Server: %s", serverReply);
    close(SOCKET);
}
```

The Server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define PORT 5010

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char msg[BUFSIZ], reply[BUFSIZ];

    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int SOCKET, ACCEPT, READ, sockSize, num1, num2, option = 1, maxClients = 30,
            h, clientSocket[maxClients], maxsd, sd, SELECT;
    fd_set readfds;
    for (h = 0; h < maxClients; h++) {
        clientSocket[h] = 0;
    }
    SOCKET = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (SOCKET == -1) {
        perror("Could not create socket");
        return -1;
    }
    if (setsockopt(SOCKET, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &option, sizeof(option)) == -1) {
        perror("Could not set OPTNAME");
        return -1;
    }
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    printf("Created socket.\n");
    if (bind(SOCKET, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Could not bind");
        return -1;
    }
    if (listen(SOCKET, 1) < 0) {
        perror("Listen failed");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Server is listening.\n");
    sockSize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while (1) {
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(SOCKET, &readfds);
        maxsd = SOCKET;
        for (h = 0; h < maxClients; h++) {
            sd = clientSocket[h];
            if (sd > 0) { FD_SET(sd, &readfds); }
            if (sd > maxsd) { maxsd = sd; }
        }
        SELECT = select(maxsd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if ((SELECT < 0) && (errno != EINTR)) {
            perror("select error");
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(SOCKET, &readfds)) {

            ACCEPT = accept(SOCKET, (struct sockaddr *) &server, (socklen_t *) &sockSize);
            if (ACCEPT < 0) {
                perror("Could not accept client");
                return -1;
            }
            for (h = 0; h < maxClients; h++) {
                if (clientSocket[h] == 0) {
                    clientSocket[h] = ACCEPT;
                    break;
                }
            }
            printf("Client has joined the server.\n");
        }
        for (h = 0; h < maxClients; h++) {
            sd = clientSocket[h];
            if (FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds)) {
                READ = read(sd, msg, sizeof(msg));
                if (READ == -1) {
                    perror("Could not receive message");
                    return -1;
                }
                if (READ == 0) {
                    printf("Client disconnected\n");
                    fflush(stdout);
                    clientSocket[h]=0;
                }
                int e = 0;
                char *p = strtok(msg, " ");
                char *arr[2];
                while (p != NULL) {
                    arr[e++] = p;
                    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
                }
                num1 = atoi(arr[0]);
                num2 = atoi(arr[1]);

                if ((strcmp(arr[0], "0") != 0 && num1 != 0) && (strcmp(arr[1], "0") != 0 && num2 != 0)) {
                    printf("Client: %d, %d\n", num1, num2);
                    sprintf(reply, "%d\n", num1 + num2);
                    if (write(sd, reply, strlen(reply)) < 0) {
                        perror("Could not send message");
                        return -1;
                    }
                    memset(&reply, 0, sizeof(reply));

                } else {
                    printf("Conversion error");
                    strcpy(reply, "Conversion error.");
                    if (write(sd, reply, strlen(reply)) < 0) {
                        perror("Could not send message");
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can the segfault be solved? How else can the codes be improved?

Comment: Which of the programs is crashing? And have you used a debugger to find out where in that program the crash happens?

Comment: On another few notes, passing an input-only stream (like `stdin`) to `fflush` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification to be *undefined behavior*. That's a rather bad habit. And all upper-case symbols are typically used for *macros* not normal variables. This is a near universal style choice. Using upper-case variable names makes your code harder to read and understand. Better rename those variables to be somewhat semantically relevant instead of using generic upper-case names.

Comment: `msg` is not NUL terminated, and you don't use the return value you get from `read()`. Also: your `if()`s in the select() loop fall-tru. (`continue;` is your friend!)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have indicated that the server is crashing. @wildplasser my ```read()``` return values are used not once, but twice; and which ```select()``` loop ```ifs``` are you talking about?

Comment: On yet another note, TCP streaming sockets are not guaranteed to receive all data sent by the other side on a single call to `read`. You might need to call `read` multiple times to receive everything. In your case I suggest you modify the client to send the string null-terminator, and then the server can read until it have received it. Then final string should include that null-terminator and you probably will have solved not only short-messages but also the problem of your crash (which I'll bet is because of the missing null-terminator).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but see that it may be difficult to implement null-terminated strings if the client is abruptly terminated

Comment: Relying only on the client to send the null-terminator might not be a good idea, you're right about that. But there's an easy solution to that (and one which you should have already done): Null-terminate the strings received in the server program.

Comment: By the way, about the conditions mentioned by @wildplasser, think about `if (READ == 0)`... What happens in that case? When and where are you actually closing the connection (and release the resources created for it)? What data do you think has been received in that case? What data will you work on?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have only closed the connection on the server side. Since my C is quite rusty, where should I implement mutual ```close``` and null-termination? And stupid question, what happens if I do not release resources?

Comment: When the other end closes its connection (i.e. when `read` returns `0`) then you need to close your end of the connection too. And if `read` doesn't return an error or other-end-closed (i.e. when `read` doesn't return `-1` or `0`) then you can use the returned value as an index to place the null-terminator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segfault comes from the `atoi` function since `NULL` is received. Checking for `NULL` seems to do the trick...